# Magento 2: UPS weight unit KGS not working

Tags: magento2, ups, product-weight

We are not able to change the weight unit from "LBS" to "KGS" in the UPS shipping settings.
If we change that we get the following error message in the checkout:
"Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time"

Our products have the KGS unit but we use an US UPS account.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What module are you using for US UPS?  I do not directly have any help other than advising that [this module I found](https://marketplace.magento.com/ups-shipping.html) **does not support US UPS**.  Also : "this extension is currently available for merchants in POLAND, FRANCE, UNITED KINGDOM, GERMANY, ITALY, SPAIN, NETHERLANDS and BELGIUM ONLY. It will be available for merchants in other countries soon. At this time, please only install this extension if you are in the above-mentioned countries."  **If this is the module, US is not supported**.

Comment: I do not use a third party module. There is already a Magento UPS module. But I think it has to do with the country US. In the error log I get the error: "Invalid Unit of Measurement for the given country".

Comment: Hi there , you need to debug further why the quotes are not available from the API response error message , make sure you have enabled the logging configurations , and check the log files or try using xdebug for more precise request and responses.Thanks